# MS Word, how to change formatting of entire paragraphs automatically in whole document?

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, rtf

I have a 20-page word document punctuated with descriptive notes throughout, like this:

> **3     Input Data Requirements**
>       Some requirement text.
>   NOTE: This is a descriptive note about the requirement, which is the paragraph that I would like to use find-and-replace or a VBA script to select automatically and change the formatting to italicized. The notes invariably end in a carriage-return: ¶.

If it was just a text document, not MS-Word, I would just use a regex in a code editor like sublime to wrap it with `<I>`...`</I>` or something along those lines.

Preferably, is there a way to do this in Word's "advanced" find-and-replace feature? Or if not, what's the best way to do it in VBA?
I've tried using a search string like this in find-and-replace: `NOTE: *[a-z0-9,. A-Z)(-]{1,255}^l` but the line-break part doesn't seem to work, and the 255 char max isn't enough for many of the paragraphs.

EDIT: Another slightly important detail: The doc is automatically generated from another piece of software as a .RTF, which I promptly converted to .docx.

Comment: Try using ^13 as your carriage return.

Comment: @Christina, thanks, that did the trick as far as matching the carriage-return.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt #2: Use Notepad++ to find and replace using regex. Remove quotes.

Find: "( NOTE: .*?)\r"

Replace with: " \i \1 \i0 \r "

***//OLD***

Sure is. No VBA or fancy tricks needed.

- CTRL + H to bring up the replace dialog.
- Click "More".
- Select "Font" in the drop down menu called "Format".
- Click italics.
- Enter find and replace text as the same thing. Make sure you set this up right so that you don't accidentally replace substrings (e.g. goal to replace all " test " with " nice ", testing -> niceing).

Should work. If you need to alter entire paragraphs, consistently, then you probably should have used the styles on those paragraphs to begin with. That way, you can change all of them at once by updating the style itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of what you outlined, though. The doc is automatically generated from another piece of software as an RTF, so making special styles from the get-go isn't an option. I need to find/select the paragraphs with something like `NOTE: [a-zA-Z0-9,.-]+(carriagereturn)` in psuedo-regex parlance and format to italics.

Comment: Shoot. Sorry about that. Why not open the RTF in sublime and then use that to wrap the NOTE: text with \i and \i0. That should be inline code for RTF that will make the text italic. Works when I brute force it, but that way you only need to get the regex right.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing exactly that in the RTF file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advance Find, yes. Find Next and then Replace makes the selection Italic.

[image]